# How can I extract an array of substring via regex in nodes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have a string var whose value is `(1,2)(3,4)` and I'd like to extract an array `[[1,2],[3,4]]` from it. The solution I have is to use `str.match` but I haven't figured out how to extract the array.
I have tried:

```
> '(1,2)(3,4)'.match(/([\d]+),([\d])*/)
[ '3,2', '3', '2', index: 1, input: '(3,2)(4,5)', groups: undefined ]
```

The result is not what I want. So what should I do with the regex for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's the other way around, without using RegExp, just in case:

```js
const src = '(1,2)(3,4)',
      
      result = src
        .slice(1,-1)
        .split(')(')
        .map(s => s.split(','))
        
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `/(\d+),(\d+)/g` or - to only get those inside parentheses - `/\((\d+),(\d+)\)/g` and get the results using `RegExp#exec` in a loop:

```js
var s = '(1,2)(3,4)', m, results=[];
var rx = /(\d+),(\d+)/g;
while(m=rx.exec(s)) {
  results.push([m[1], m[2]])
}
console.log(results);
```

Or, with `matchAll` if you target the latest JS environments:

```js
const s = '(1,2)(3,4)', rx = /(\d+),(\d+)/g;
const results = [...s.matchAll(rx)];
console.log(Array.from(results, x => [x[1],x[2]]))
```